# Email Sending Python App does not send emails after switching from Microsoft SQL Server Management DB to Snowflake

Tags: python, sql-server, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, smtplib

I had built a Python based app that connects to a Microsoft SQL Server Management database and sends login details to users.

However, we have recently changed from Microsoft SQL Server Management to Snowflake and doesn't fully work.

I am able to connect to the Snowflake database and search through the accounts. It is only when I click on the button that should trigger the email sending that the console produces an error.

Here is the code for the function that should trigger the emails:

```
# Send login details button
def send_logins(retailer):
    c.execute("""SELECT Retailer, Retailer_Name, Contact, E_Mail, Account_ID, Password FROM Retailers WHERE Retailer = ? """, (retailer[0]))
    users = c.fetchall()
    # Create a secure SSL context
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    with smtplib.SMTP_SSL(smtp_server, port, context=context) as server:
        try:
            server.login(sender_email, password)
        except SMTPAuthenticationError:
            print("Username and/or password you entered is incorrect")
        try:
            missing = []
            for Retailer, Retailer_Name, Contact, E_Mail, Account_ID, Password in users:
                valid = True
                if not Retailer_Name:
                    missing.append("Business has no name!")
                    valid = False
                if not Account_ID:
                    missing.append("Business has no username!")
                    valid = False
                if not Password:
                    missing.append("Business has no password!")
                    valid = False
                if not E_Mail:
                    missing.append("Business has no email address!")
                    valid = False
                if not Contact:
                    Contact = ' '
                    valid = True
                if valid:
                    server.sendmail(
                            sender_email,
                            E_Mail.split(';'),
                            message.as_string().format(
                                Retailer_Name=Retailer_Name,
                                Contact=Contact,
                                E_Mail=E_Mail,
                                previous_month=previous_month,
                                year=year,
                                Account_ID=Account_ID,
                                Password=Password,
                                comp_logo=comp_logo,
                                comp_twitter=comp_twitter,
                                comp_linkedin=comp_linkedin,
                                comp_insta=comp_insta),
                    )
                    server.sendmail(
                            sender_email,
                            E_Mail.split(';'),
                            message2.as_string().format(
                                Retailer_Name=Retailer_Name,
                                Contact=Contact,
                                E_Mail=E_Mail,
                                previous_month=previous_month,
                                year=year,
                                Account_ID=Account_ID,
                                Password=Password,
                                comp_logo=comp_logo,
                                comp_twitter=comp_twitter,
                                comp_linkedin=comp_linkedin,
                                comp_insta=comp_insta),
                    )
                    if valid:
                        print("Emails sent to " + str(Contact) + " at " + str(Retailer_Name))
                        sent_outcome_label.config(text="Emails sent to " + str(Contact) + " at " + str(Retailer_Name))
                        missing_fields_label.config(text="")
                else:
                    print("Emails not sent to " + str(Retailer_Name) + "!")
                    sent_outcome_label.config(text="Emails not sent to " + str(Contact) + " at " + str(Retailer_Name) + ":")
                    missing_fields_label.config(text=("\n".join(missing)))
                    print(missing)
        except SMTPException as e2:
            print(e2)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Emails not sent!")
            print(e)
```

Example of the data that should be appearing in the SELECT statement:

| Retailer | Retailer_Name | Contact | E-Mail | Account_ID | Password |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | Business One | Bob | Example@example.com | 1000 | Ghy235G |
| 1001 | Business Two | Rob | Example1@example.com | 1001 | tFz145f |

The error that appears in the console:

```
  File "C:\Users\Person\OneDrive - Company\Documents\Python\Comp Interface\sil_sf_resend_app.py", line 599, in <lambda>                                                                                                                                
    send_login_button = ttk.Button(frame_send_logins, text="Yes", width=10, command=lambda: send_logins(retailer))                                                                                                                                                    
  File "C:\Users\Person\OneDrive - Company\Documents\Python\Comp Interface\sil_sf_resend_app.py", line 380, in send_logins                                                                                                                             
    c.execute("""SELECT Retailer, Retailer_Name, Contact, E_Mail, Account_ID, Password FROM Retailers WHERE Retailer = ? """, (retailer[0]))                                                                                                                          
  File "C:\Users\Person\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\snowflake\connector\cursor.py", line 660, in execute                                                                                                                                  
    if params is not None and len(params) == 0:                                                                                                                                                                                                                       
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

I have a feeling it is something to do with the c.execute statement and the ? placeholder but having no luck at all!

I am trying to include as much information as possible without exposing any sensitive info but please let me know if there are other parts of my code that you would like to see.

Comment: The second argument of `c.execute()` expects a tuple or list, so `c.execute("...", (retailer[0]))` should be `c.execute("...", [retailer[0]])` instead.

Comment: @acw1668 thanks for your quick response. I have made the changes and I now get a slightly different console error at the end: query = command % processed_params. TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting.

Comment: @acw1668 I have found the issue. After making your recommended change, I also had to change the '?' to '%s' as the placeholder as that's how Snowflake accepts it! Will add a comment with your answer and my amends and mark as correct! Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

So with the help of @acw1668, I had to change the SELECT statement from:

```
c.execute("""SELECT Retailer, Retailer_Name, Contact, E_Mail, Account_ID, Password FROM Retailers where Retailer = ? """, (retailer[0]))
```

to:

```
c.execute("""SELECT Retailer, Retailer_Name, Contact, E_Mail, Account_ID, Password FROM Retailers WHERE Retailer = %s """, [retailer[0]])
```

Note the change in brackets around 'retailer.' This is because the second argument of c.execute() expects a tuple or list.

I then also found out that the placeholder works differently in Snowflake compared to SQL. I had to replace the '?' to '%s'